# curl & xmllint working together on AIX

Tags: curl, aix, xmllint

I wish to use the commands **curl** & **xmllint** on by AIX box. To make them work, I have had to add entries into my **LIBPATH** variable. However, I cannot seem to get them to work together.

When my **`LIBPATH=/opt/freeware/lib64/:/opt/freeware/lib/:/usr/lib/`**, **xmllint** works fine, but **curl** doesn't. [curl_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bANE.png)

When my **`LIBPATH=/opt/freeware/lib64/:/usr/lib`**, **curl** works fine but **xmllint** doesn't.[xmllint_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrkm9.png)

Is there a way to get them both working together? Am I missing any library imports? I do not have much knowledge on the package installation steps though and I do not have root access.

My $PATH contains the value `/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/bin`

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world [meaning: if the linkage had happened with the proper `-blibpath` and `-bipath` options], you could unset `LIBPATH` and everything would work. If it isn't so, you can create launcher scripts, eg:

```
cat /opt/freeware/bin/curl.sh

#!/bin/sh
export LIBPATH=<whatever_it_needs>
exec /opt/freeware/bin/curl
```

Edit: before solving the problem, you should examine your binaries with `dump -H -X32_64` to find out their dependencies (command `ldd` is useful, too). Example:

```
$ dump -H -X32_64 /usr/local/bin/curl
/usr/local/bin/curl:
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER              
0      /usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib                                          
1      /usr/local/lib                libcrypto.so.1.0.2                      
2      /usr/local/lib                libcurl.so.4                            
3      /usr/local/lib                libgcc_s.a          shr.o               
4      /usr/local/lib                libiconv.so.2                           
5      /usr/local/lib                libidn.so.11                            
6      /usr/local/lib                libintl.so.8                            
7      /usr/local/lib                libssl.so.1.0.2                         
8      /usr/local/lib                libz.so.1                               
9      /usr/local/lib                libcpotlas.so.1                         
10     /usr/lib                      libpthreads.a       shr_xpg5.o          
11     /usr/lib                      libc.a              shr.o

$ dump -H -X32_64 /usr/local/bin/xmllint
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER              
0      /usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib                                         
1      /usr/local/lib64              libgcc_s.a          shr.o               
2      /usr/local/lib64              libiconv.so.2                           
3      /usr/local/lib64              liblzma.so.5                            
4      /usr/local/lib64              libxml2.so.2                            
5      /usr/local/lib64              libz.so.1                               
6      /usr/local/lib64              libcpotlas.so.1                         
7      /usr/lib                      libpthreads.a       shr_xpg5_64.o       
8      /usr/lib                      libc.a              shr_64.o
```

In these cases dependencies have file-paths, so no LIBPATH required at all

Comment: If understand correctly, the suggestion would be to clear the LIBPATH just before the command > set the new LIBPATH and execute the command? But, Im trying to create a shell script which would make a webservice call using curl, while parsing the response using the xmllint command. So isn't there any way for them to work using a single environment import? But just to let you know, this does work on Linux & Cygwin.

Comment: Edited my answer. Also I started to write something about linking in linux: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Lorinczy. I did use ldd, but later my Unix admin made some changes to get it to work. Will post the solution once I get the changes which were done. Too low rep to give a public up-vote :(